# How to use unsplit() to vertically join multiple data frames?

Tags: r

I have multiple data frames in R with exactly same structure, and I want to merge them vertically in a single data frame. `unsplit()` seems like a right function to do. However, I was not able to make it work.

Eventually I reduced it all to this simple case:

```
> df <- data.frame("ch" = c("A", "B"), "num" = c(1, 2));
> df
  ch num
1  A   1
2  B   2


> divided <- split(df, df$ch);
> divided
$A
  ch num
1  A   1

$B
  ch num
2  B   2


> changed <- lapply(divided, function (x) {data.frame("ch" = x$ch, "num" = x$num + 1)})
> changed
$A
  ch num
1  A   2

$B
  ch num
1  B   3


> unsplit(changed, df$ch)
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘1’
```

So the question is - why didn't `unsplit()` work in this case? What would be a right way to use that function?

P.S. I'm able to solve my task by using `do.call('rbind', changed)`, but this question is about correct usage of `unsplit()`.

Comment: Read the error: you've got duplicate row names, which `unsplit` uses to recombine. From `?unsplit`: "In the data frame case, row names are obtained by unsplitting the row name vectors from the elements of `value`."

Comment: Thanks @alistaire - I was trying to decode all that, but it's like going into a recursive rabbit hole - unsplit() -> elements -> row names -> unsplit()... And the message which mentions `*tmp*` value was also not helpful (I don't know whether it is a string, or some placeholder in the error output...). So seeing the way to fix it and clear explanation of what data entries conflict with what functions - would be great.

Comment: It's not worth fixing; `unsplit` is a mostly useless function, as without significant finagling it can only combine something split by `split`. `do.call(rbind, ... )` is the general way to recombine a list of data.frames in R, though dplyr and data.table have more powerful alternatives, `bind_rows` and `rbindlist`.

Comment: I believe `do.call("rbind", ...)` should be slower than `unsplit()` or other function which is directly designed to merge multiple data frames. Because `do.call` merely runs the same function multiple times, without any optimization for the whole process. While `unsplit()` sees the forest, not just trees - and thus is able to improve the speed of the process. That's why I wanted to understand the case with `unsplit()`.

Comment: I benchmarked on an equivalent data.frame with 250 groups and 1E5 observations using ProcrastinatusMaximus's answer from below, and `unsplit` was took more than twice as long as `do.call(rbind, ... )` on average over 100 replications. The minimum for `unsplit` was still longer than the maximum for `do.call`. For the small data in the question, they're almost precisely equivalent. `bind_rows` and `rbindlist` are both two orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Thanks for that. The results are strange for me, this should be exactly opposite. I wonder, how that's implemented internally... But I won't have enough time to investigate that. But thanks again for the benchmark results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** After splitting, increment `num` without reconstructing the component data frames from scratch like this:

```
L <- lapply(divided, transform, num = num+1)
```

Then `unsplit` will work:

```
> unsplit(L, df$ch)
  ch num
1  A   2
2  B   3
```

**2)** If you must reconstruct the data frames from scratch but are keeping the number of rows the same in each component then use the original row names.  Here is your code except that we have added `row.names=`.  Now it works:

```
 changed2 <- lapply(divided, 
   function (x) data.frame(ch = x$ch, num = x$num + 1, row.names = rownames(x)))
 unsplit(changed2, df$ch)
```

**3)** If you are reconstructing the data frames so that there are more rows then you will need to synthesize new unique row names such as, for example, in @Mark Peterson's solution.

Comment: Thanks for the full picture of various methods how to solve this issue. BTW - how does `num = num+1` work in the first case? I expect that the passed arguments should be calculated by R before it actually executes the function. So `num = num+1` says something like "take variable `num`, add 1 to it and then pass it to the function as a parameter with the name "num". But at that point `num` variable is not defined, therefore it is not possible to add 1 to it... And therefore I'd except to see an error when doing that function call.

Comment: (1) is equivalent to `lapply(divided, function(x) transform(x, num = num + 1))`.   See `?transform` for more info.

Comment: I can speculate how the latter equivalent might work - there's a lambda with closure, and `num` can be introduced there by a higher context (though R is a static context language, not dynamic - so it is still unclear how `num` gets there, because it is not defined anywhere in the contexts wrapping the call). But for the original example from (1) still the language mechanism is not clear. Probably I need to read more thoroughly the spec on language syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to manually override the rownames to avoid the "duplicate rownames" error, e.g.,:

```
changed <- lapply(divided, function (x) {
  temp <- data.frame("ch" = x$ch, "num" = x$num + 1)
  row.names(temp) <-
    paste(x$ch, 1:nrow(x), sep = ".")

  return(temp)  
  })

unsplit(changed, df$ch)
```

As an aside, check out `bind_rows` from `dplyr` as an alternative to using `do.call` that may make you more willing to just walk away from `unsplit`

Comment: Cool, will debug the solution. So you're saying that the issue is that `divided` was formed by `split()` which assigned "labels" - row names from the `df` structure - to each row of the new data frame. And thus `unsplit()` is able to combine the data frames back from `divided`, because all the row names are unique. But it's not the case for `changed`... Ok... This seems like a need for improvement in the `unsplit()` function, because in majority of the cases one doesn't need to keep the labels, rather he needs just to merge the rows and re-index their names.

Comment: I would argue that there are enough better tools out there that there is little cause for changing the behavior of `unsplit` I am not sure that there are any cases where it's behavior is superior to `bind_rows` or even `do.call(rbind, listOfDFs)`